# YII 2 - metronic theme integration

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am new in yii 2,
 I am trying to integrate metronic theme in yii2 application,
I refer this website https://github.com/dlds/yii2-metronic for integration.. 
  error  `Fatal error: Class 'dlds\metronic\Metronic' not found in C:\wamp\www\basic\config\web.php`,
    please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

have you edit your config/web.php with this code:

```
'components' => [
'metronic'=>[
    'class'=>'dlds\metronic\Metronic',
    'resources'=>'[path to my web]/web/metronic/assets/theme/assets',
    'style'=>\dlds\metronic\Metronic::STYLE_MATERIAL,
    'theme'=>\dlds\metronic\Metronic::THEME_LIGHT,
    'layoutOption'=>\dlds\metronic\Metronic::LAYOUT_FLUID,
    'headerOption'=>\dlds\metronic\Metronic::HEADER_FIXED,
    'sidebarPosition'=>\dlds\metronic\Metronic::SIDEBAR_POSITION_LEFT,
    'sidebarOption'=>\dlds\metronic\Metronic::SIDEBAR_MENU_ACCORDION,
    'footerOption'=>\dlds\metronic\Metronic::FOOTER_FIXED,
],]
```

You must be sure where you loaded the component in this line:

```
'resources'=>'[path to my web]/web/metronic/assets/theme/assets',
```